# User badges not showing reputation or badge counts

Tags: bug, user-interface, users

On all questions  (at least on SO and MSE), I'm no longer seeing badge counts or reputation numbers on user badges on posts (both answers and questions):

[image]

Is this intended? Part of testing going on? Or just a bug?

Comment: Most likely another test, just like the voting counter on questions. They might be testing "blind voting" a bit more.

Comment: I've just noticed this too and was going to post a question about it.

Comment: I noticed this too and appears to be happening with yourself for me too. I've noticed in some questions it's not happening, a bit of an inconsistency

Comment: Looks like it is on all sites

Comment: Btw that's being asked here too: [User cards are no longer showing reputation or badges across the network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/334878), so I guess you can safely delete your question here.